# How to add a different bg-image to each li by scss?

Tags: sass

I have an unordered list like that

```
<div id="target_familie" class="votes rb3">
 <ul>
  <li><h2>Something else in here</h2></li>
  <li><h3>Background 1 here</li>
  <li><h3>Background 2 here</li>
  <li><h3>Background 3 here</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

and trying to add a different background image to each of these li-elements by doing this:

```
@for $i from 1 through 4 {
    .votes li:nth-of-type(#{$i})
    {
    background: url('../bilder/keyvisual_'$i'.png') no-repeat;

   }
}
```

But that just made a result like **url("../bilder/keyvisual_" 3 ".png") no-repeat**

And that's obviously not correct due to the I also tried to write the url like that:

```
background: url('../bilder/keyvisual_#{$i}.png') no-repeat;
```

but that didn't work at all.

So you may already have seen, I want `bilder/keyvisual_1.png` to be the background of the first `li` and `bilder/keyvisual_2.png` of the second `li` and so on...

I guess there could be a solution with using a helping variable upfrontal, but I didn't come to a solution by that neither.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I copied your code and it worked just fine: http://sassmeister.com/gist/c53f148af2b2155ec20c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Sass code should be like:

```
@for $i from 1 through 4 {
    .votes li:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
        background: url('../bilder/keyvisual_#{$i}.png') no-repeat;
    }
}
```

Check it out in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/albertmatyi/atdknn0x/)

Note: In the fiddle I added an  `&:after { content:'#{$i}'; }` to make the rendered `i` visible

Comment: I don't see how this is different from the code the OP provided.  If you can't reproduce a problem, then the question should be closed as "not reproducible".

Comment: @cimmanon If you look closely, the OP didn't interpolate `$i` and this answer did; that's the solution to the problem.

Comment: @allejo Reread the question.  The initial example does not use interpolation but goes on to show that they tried interpolation, but "but that didn't work at all".

Comment: @cimmanon Well that's embarrassing, I didn't notice that part of the question. You are right!